# Image Analysis in Bokeh?

Tags: python, user-interface, bokeh

I am looking to replace a MATLAB GUI used to do manual scoring of objects within a tif file. Someone recommended Bokeh to me. Is it possible to read a tif-file using any module and allow interactivity via Bokeh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Bokeh (but I have kept an eye on it), so my answer is: Yes, you could probably use Bokeh for this.

But considering that you are replacing a MATLAB GUI, I think there might be an easier way. Bokeh creates plots that run in your web browser, which might not be what you want.

Instead, you could look into using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) to do it.
The PyPlot API in matplotlib is very similar to the plot functions in MATLAB, and it supports creating interactive plots.

To read the TIFF file I would recommend looking into either [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).

Comment: Could I integrate the plotting/visualization functionality of matplotlib/PIL into a GUI wrapper like pyside?

Comment: I don't think I have tried pyside, but I have integrated matplotlib with Qt using the PyQt bindings without any trouble.